# Create rows in html which will share height?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div calss="row" style="height:20%; display: block;">
        <h1>20 percent height</h1>
    </div>
    <div calss="row">
        <h1>height should be 80 percent</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried some example which is shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wqkLodb6/) but it's not working.
My requirement is if i keep first height as 10% or 20% second row should occupy height automatically without setting the height explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use flexbox for this type of stuff.  Also instead of 80 and 20 you could use 4 and 1, it's just the ratio that matters

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.top {
  flex: 80;
  background: red;
}

.bottom {
  flex: 20;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `flex` display. Add `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` for the parent and for the second content provide `flex-grow: 1` which will fit that div in rest of the space.

```css
.container-fluid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 500px;
}
.container-fluid div {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.row-two {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" style="height:20%; display: block;">
    <h1>20 percent height</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-two">
    <h1>height should be 80 percent</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```